# Auto scaling docker containers in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, autoscaling

We can scale docker containers using service auto scaling feature in AWS with the help of Cloud-watch Alarms - 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_autoscaling_tutorial.html

Is there any other options are available to scale the docker container if the CPU/Memory utilization reaches 80% without using Cloud-watch?

Note: We can achieve the same in Kubernetes using horizontal pod auto scaling. I want to achieve the same in AWS without Cloudwatch support.

Comment: why do you not want to use cloudwatch?

Answer (score -1):

You can use AWS ECS to scale docker containers. It provides a native orchestration platform to AWS as well as support for Kubernetes.

If you decides to use ECS native container orchestration, it involves a learning curve where you need to understand ECS specific terms such as Tasks, Services and etc. The same goes with Kubernetes where you need to understand Pods, Services and etc.

When using ECS, it manages the underlying complexities such as placing containers across multiple EC2s which powers the container cluster, supporting Load Balancer intergration for container level load balancing, Supporting fault tolerance by replacing unhealthy containers and etc.

It is also possible to use AWS Fargate which also comes with ECS, where the underlying nodes in the cluster is entirely managed by AWS without even exposing the number of EC2s powering the cluster. It is more like you can scale up and down to large number of containers without worrying about allocating EC2s to the cluster. However,  it is expensive in comparison which limits its usage for more specific workloads that requires higher levels of scalability with least predictability which justifies the pricing.

Comment: ECS autoscaling uses cloudwatch alarms. OP specifically asked about not using CW.

Comment: Though the default option comes with CF you can implement your own monitoring and use ECS Apis to scale.(Check the updated answe)

Comment: This answer provides no meaningful information to people pursuing this question.

Comment: @troyfolger Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the answer with more details. Hope it helps.